# Is anyone using QGIS as an educational tool?

Tags: qgis, education

Here at the Cranedale Centre we are interested in knowing if any schools, collages and universities are using QGIS in their classrooms for education.

We are using it for teaching both GCSE and A Level Geography and Biology specifications (ages 15-18 in the UK) and would greatly value connecting with any other similar users.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is really an invitation to discussion, and does not fit in the focused Q&A model used by GIS SE.

Comment: The best places to connect are probably the QGIS user mailing list and the OSGeo Geo4all education initiative.